# Set Owner of Directory and Sub Containers in C#

Tags: c#, windows-server-2008-r2

When setting the owner of a preexisting folder in Server 2008 R2, is there a way to make this propagate to all of the sub containers under the object? You can do this in the Properties diag, but I do not see a switch for this.

I am looking for a way to avoid recusing through the sub containers to do this.

This code will switch the owner for only the top level directory.

```
DirectoryInfo myDirectoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo("PATH HERE");
DirectorySecurity myDirectorySecurity = myDirectoryInfo.GetAccessControl();

System.Security.Principal.IdentityReference myOwner = 
    new System.Security.Principal.NTAccount("TARGET OWNER ACCOUNT");
myDirectorySecurity.SetOwner(myOwner);

myDirectoryInfo.SetAccessControl(myDirectorySecurity);
```

Answer (score 0):

[There is no overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.setaccesscontrol(v=vs.110).aspx) that will provide this for you.

But the following code will do that:

```
DirectoryInfo directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(path);
var directories = directoryInfo.EnumerateDirectories("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
foreach (var directory in directories)
{
    // set owner                
}
```

Note that I use `EnumerateDirectories` instead of `Directory.GetDirectories`, it will return instantly even if there are 1000's of directories.

Comment: It will return them all, but then you must set the owner on each one in the foreach statement. Meaning more run time to do that.

Comment: This operation takes time as well in Windows, if you are concerned with UI freezes or whatever, run the method asynchronously and report progress using Progress<T>.